# Poweshell Banner Hidden

Tags: powershell, terminal, python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to hide this PowerShell branding that is shown in the VSCode terminal?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

Need someone to help me hide it. Also if there is a way to hide the file path shown in the terminal, that would be awesome as well!

Comment: You can write your own prompt function that replaces the prompt. In the same script where you place your prompt function, you can do a cls and print whatever you want to replace the banner.

Comment: This is what the -NoLogo switch is for in your settings.json file